# How to proceed to next API request after successful authentication in Google Auth 2.0 in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, google-authentication

How to proceed to next api request after successful authication in google auth2.0 in iPhone?  I got return data with keys. I need to use calendar api and task api.

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {


NSString *nextURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/mymail@gmail.com"];
 //i just gave this url for testing. dont know which url is required here.
NSURL *nextURL = [NSURL URLWithString:nextURLString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nextURL];
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
if (error != nil) {
    // Authentication failed
} else {
    // Authentication succeeded

    [fetcher setAuthorizer:auth];
}
```

}

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Go through the [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)